# How to set up the CNAME in DNS zone record to work with Unbounce

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, hosting, subdomain, cname-record

I'm trying to run split testing on some landing pages I "designed" with Unbounce, but it requires that I set the CNAME record for my domain/sub-domain and I'm having trouble figuring out what is the right way to do it. My host is arvixe (www.arvixe.com) and their customer support has failed to help me for the past 5 days (I spoke to them multiple times).

I followed the directions for setting the CNAME record and I was able to set the CNAME record, but I'm consistently unable to verify that the CNAME record is set up correctly. I followed the [instructions on Unbounce to verify the CNAME record](http://support.unbounce.com/entries/20316718-how-can-i-verify-that-my-cname-record-is-set-up-correctly) for my sub-domain ([beta.devboost.com](http://beta.devboost.com)) and here are the results:

```
No records found
reverse lookup  smtp diag   port scan   blacklist

Reported by ns1.SNARE.arvixe.com on Thursday, November 10, 2011 at 5:49:57 PM (GMT-6)
```

Here is my DNS zone record from the control panel of my host (last record, `CNAME unbouncepages.com`): 
[image: DNS Zone Record]

Is there something wrong with my DNS Zone Record? What's the right way to do this?

**Update:**
I also have a CNAME record for `beta` in my root domain ([devboost.com](http://www.devboost.com)):
[image]

I've updated my sub-domain record now: I've removed most of the other DNS records and I've removed the `beta` label for the CNAME record: 
[image]

Is that correct? Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: You have more problems with zone than CNAME

Comment: >nslookup beta.devboost.com

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    beta.devboost.com
Address:  65.98.33.193

Comment: >nslookup mail.devboost.com

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    ghs.l.google.com
Address:  209.85.143.121
Aliases:  mail.devboost.com, ghs.google.com

Comment: @LazyBadger, I registered my domain with a different provider and I transferred hosting to arvixe.com, so I assume that this is the reason I'm getting the non-authoritative answer. However, and forgive my ignorance, I'm not sure why that would be a problem...

Comment: Write here **your business-task**, not technical - you mess all in technical part into terrible mix

Comment: @LazyBadger, thanks for the patience! My **business task** is to [setup my sub-domain (beta.devboost.com) to point to unbouncepages.com](http://support.unbounce.com/entries/20316578-how-do-i-set-up-my-custom-domain). I have two DMZ records: one for beta.devboost.com and the other one for devboost.com, which one should contain the CNAME record?

Comment: @LazyBadger thanks! It's a pain in the ass to deal with this, so I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: all extremely bad&mad

Long answer

```
> Quering 65.98.33.192 for {beta.devboost.com.,ANY}
; Answer ID: 18467  QR: true  OPCODE: QUERY  AA: true  TC: false  RD: true
; RA: false  RCODE: NOERROR  qc 1  an 6  au 0  ad 2

; Question section:
;beta.devboost.com. IN ANY

; Answer section:
beta.devboost.com. 1d IN MX 10 mail.beta.devboost.com. 
beta.devboost.com. 1d IN MX 21 mail2.beta.devboost.com. 
beta.devboost.com. 1d IN A 65.98.33.193 
beta.devboost.com. 1d IN SOA ns1.SNARE.arvixe.com. hostmaster.beta.devboost.com. 2011111006 3600 600 1209600 86400 
beta.devboost.com. 1d IN NS ns2.SNARE.arvixe.com. 
beta.devboost.com. 1d IN NS ns1.SNARE.arvixe.com.
```

Ok, it **seems as subdomain** of devboost, but - I can't AXFR devboost zone from primary NS (bad one) for verify, screenshot show me **useless CNAME** record **instead of mandatory NS** glue records (bad two)

## **ADD**: Final observaton

Well, now I have read Unbounce "KB" and I have to say only one: "Forget this crap". In order to get landing page on Unbounce web-server for **host beta.devboost.com** in **domain devboost.com** you have

- remove subdomain beta., **totally**
- <strike>add RR (host) beta into domain devboost.com with type CNAME, pointing to unbouncepages.com (record idetical to CNAME record on screenshot for beta. subdomain)</strike>I overlooked CNAME, you already have it in zone
- Nothing more, after expiration time for old bad data you'll see expected result

Comment: RA: false means also ns1.SNARE.arvixe.com. not considered as authoritative for domain beta.

Comment: ! ROCK ON!!!! That was it! Thanks a **lot** for the help!

Answer (score 1):

As specified your CNAME is for `beta.beta.devboost.com`.  If you have a CNAME for `beta.devboost.com` it has to be specified in the `devboost.com` domain.  Also, you can't have any other records `NS`, `MX`, `SOA`, sub-domains, etc for `beta.deboost.com` if it is a CNAME.

EDIT You need to remove all the `beta` sub-domain records for the sub-domain, and the domain.  You may need to remove the `NS` records for `beta` from the domain first.  By configuring NS records for the sub-domain, you are delegating authority for the sub-domain to those name servers.

To have a CNAME for `beta`, the CNAME needs to be defined in the `devboost.com` domain, and be the only record for `beta`.  As a CNAME `beta` is not allowed to have sub-domains, or any other records.

It is not necessary to delegate to sub-domains.  These can be handled by the domain.  Defining `mail.beta` in the domain is equivalent to defining `mail` in the `beta` sub-domain.

Comment: I tried to delete the NS, but the I get an error message: `"Cannot delete NS record - DNS zone must include at least two NS records."` I have deleted everything else, but the NS, the CNAME records and the records for cp, ftp and mail. Should I delete the cp, ftp and mail records as well?

Comment: You need to remove the delegation from `devboost.com` and define the CNAME record there.

Comment: what do you mean when you say "the delegation from `devboost.com`"? In `devboost.com`, I also has a CNAME record for `beta` and it's also pointing to `unbouncepages.com`, is that correct? Sorry, I'm just a total noob when it comes to web hosting.

Comment: It's not webhosting, it's hostmastering, which also a task of professionals